# Execution of VBA code gets slow after many iterations

Tags: performance, excel, vba, iteration

I have written a little sub to filter approx. 56.000 items in an Excel List.

It works as expected, but it gets really slower and slower after like 30.000 Iterations. After 100.000 Iterations it's really slow...

The Sub checks each row, if it contains any of the defined words (KeyWords Array). If true, it checks if it is a false positive and afterwards deletes it.

What am I missing here? Why does it get so slow?

Thanks...

```
Private Sub removeAllOthers()
'
' removes all Rows where Name does not contain
' LTG, Leitung...
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Dim TotalRows As Long
TotalRows = Cells(rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row

' Define all words with meaning "Leitung"
KeyWords = Array("LTG", "LEITUNG", "LETG", "LEITG", "MASSE")

' Define all words which are false positives"
BadWords = Array("DUMMY", "BEF", "HALTER", "VORSCHALTGERAET", _
                 "VORLAUFLEITUNG", "ANLEITUNG", "ABSCHIRMUNG", _
                 "AUSGLEICHSLEITUNG", "ABDECKUNG", "KAELTEMITTELLEITUNG", _
                 "LOESCHMITTELLEITUNG", "ROHRLEITUNG", "VERKLEIDUNG", _
                 "UNTERDRUCK", "ENTLUEFTUNGSLEITUNG", "KRAFTSTOFFLEITUNG", _
                 "KST", "AUSPUFF", "BREMSLEITUNG", "HYDRAULIKLEITUNG", _
                 "KUEHLLEITUNG", "LUFTLEITUNG", "DRUCKLEITUNG", "HEIZUNGSLEITUNG", _
                 "OELLEITUNG", "RUECKLAUFLEITUNG", "HALTESCHIENE", _
                 "SCHLAUCHLEITUNG", "LUFTMASSE", "KLEBEMASSE", "DICHTUNGSMASSE")

For i = TotalRows To MIN_ROW Step -1

    Dim nmbr As Long
    nmbr = TotalRows - i

    If nmbr Mod 20 = 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & nmbr & " of " & TotalRows - MIN_ROW & ": " & Format(nmbr / (TotalRows - MIN_ROW), "Percent")
    End If

    Set C = Range(NAME_COLUMN & i)

    Dim Val As Variant
    Val = C.Value

    Dim found As Boolean

    For Each keyw In KeyWords
        found = InStr(1, Val, keyw) <> 0
        If (found) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Check if LTG contains Bad Word
    Dim badWord As Boolean

    If found Then

        'Necessary because SCHALTER contains HALTER
        If InStr(1, Val, "SCHALTER") = 0 Then
            'Bad Word filter
            For Each badw In BadWords
                badWord = InStr(1, Val, badw) <> 0
                If badWord Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

        End If
    End If

    If found = False Or badWord = True Then
        C.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next i

Application.StatusBar = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: A more efficient approach would be to add a working column (using VBA) to return TRUE or FALSE for each row againt your keywords, then use AutoFilter to remove the unwanted rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, performing read from / write to operations on ranges in long loops are slow, compared to loops that are performed in memory.
A more performant approach would be to load the range into memory, perform the operations in memory (on array level), clear the contents of the entire range and display the new result (after operations on the array) at once in the sheet (no constant Read / Write but only Read and Write a single time).

Below you find a test with 200 000 rows that illustrates what I aim at, I suggest you check it out. 
If it is not a hundred percent what you were looking for, you can finetune it in any way you wish.
I noticed that the screen becomes blank at a certain point; don't do anything, the code is still running but you may be temporarily blocked out of the Excel application.
However you'll notice that it is faster.

```
Sub Test()

Dim BadWords            As Variant
Dim Keywords            As Variant

Dim oRange              As Range
Dim iRange_Col          As Integer
Dim lRange_Row          As Long
Dim vArray              As Variant
Dim lCnt                As Long
Dim lCnt_Final          As Long
Dim keyw                As Variant
Dim badw                As Variant
Dim val                 As String
Dim found               As Boolean
Dim badWord             As Boolean
Dim vArray_Final()      As Variant


Keywords = Array("LTG", "LEITUNG", "LETG", "LEITG", "MASSE")

BadWords = Array("DUMMY", "BEF", "HALTER", "VORSCHALTGERAET", _
             "VORLAUFLEITUNG", "ANLEITUNG", "ABSCHIRMUNG", _
             "AUSGLEICHSLEITUNG", "ABDECKUNG", "KAELTEMITTELLEITUNG", _
             "LOESCHMITTELLEITUNG", "ROHRLEITUNG", "VERKLEIDUNG", _
             "UNTERDRUCK", "ENTLUEFTUNGSLEITUNG", "KRAFTSTOFFLEITUNG", _
             "KST", "AUSPUFF", "BREMSLEITUNG", "HYDRAULIKLEITUNG", _
             "KUEHLLEITUNG", "LUFTLEITUNG", "DRUCKLEITUNG", "HEIZUNGSLEITUNG", _
             "OELLEITUNG", "RUECKLAUFLEITUNG", "HALTESCHIENE", _
             "SCHLAUCHLEITUNG", "LUFTMASSE", "KLEBEMASSE", "DICHTUNGSMASSE")


Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A200000")
iRange_Col = oRange.Columns.Count
lRange_Row = oRange.Rows.Count
ReDim vArray(1 To lRange_Row, 1 To iRange_Col)
vArray = oRange

For lCnt = 1 To lRange_Row
    Application.StatusBar = lCnt

   val = vArray(lCnt, 1)

   For Each keyw In Keywords
       found = InStr(1, val, keyw) <> 0
       If (found) Then
           Exit For
       End If
   Next

    If found Then
       'Necessary because SCHALTER contains HALTER
       If InStr(1, val, "SCHALTER") = 0 Then
           'Bad Word filter
           For Each badw In BadWords
               badWord = InStr(1, val, badw) <> 0
               If badWord Then
                   Exit For
               End If
           Next
       End If
   End If

    If found = False Or badWord = True Then
    Else
        'Load values into a new array
        lCnt_Final = lCnt_Final + 1
        ReDim Preserve vArray_Final(1 To lCnt_Final)
        vArray_Final(lCnt_Final) = vArray(lCnt, 1)
    End If

Next lCnt

oRange.ClearContents
set oRange = nothing

If lCnt_Final <> 0 Then
    Set oRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lCnt_Final, 1))
    oRange = vArray_Final
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the meantime I found a similar approach (could not post it tough as I had to wait 8 hours :P)
  If Not found Or badWord Then
        'C.EntireRow.Delete
        If ToDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set ToDelete = Range(i & ":" & i)
        Else
            Set ToDelete = Union(ToDelete, Range(i & ":" & i))
        End If
    End If
And afterwards select the range at once.. 
If Not ToDelete Is Nothing Then
    ToDelete.Select
    Selection.Delete
End If

200.000 Items will be checked within approx. 7 Minutes in contrast to 26. minutes before..

Comment: What do you mean 7 minutes? With my code it hardly took a minute to check 200 000 rows...

Comment: Sounds good.. I will try your solution in the next days and see if it improves even more.. Thank you..

Comment: I would check to see if setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of your sub (then `True` at the end) would also create an impact.

Comment: That's true when performing many screenupdates indeed. For my code, It will not make a big difference since all updates are performed directly in memory.